# Unable to view First Edittext when virtual keyboard is visible

Tags: android

In the Linearlayout I have four Edittext Fields.When virtual Keyboard is opened I can't able to view the first edittext field.I can able to scroll from the second view, First view is partially visible. How to solve this.Thanks in advance.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/scrlLogin"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Title" android:background="@drawable/screenbackground"
    android:scrollbars="none">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_gravity="center">

             ..............
</LinearLayout >
</ScrollView >
```

My Screen Links are here

[Normal Screen](http://i45.tinypic.com/1zl8ync.png)

[With Virtual Keyboard](http://i45.tinypic.com/10qdnon.png)

Comment: I can't able attach screen shot.Because more than 10 reputation holders only can able to upload screen shots

Comment: Upload it to a image hoster and post link here. edit: and post your whole layout, maybe the error is with your edittext fields

Comment: I had upload the screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't waste your time
Just put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml in main activity.